# Ruby on Rails 3.0 JQuery Validation Remote

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins

I am using the JQuery Validation plugin to validate a sign up form on my website.

I want to use a remote call to see if an email exists.

However, I am having difficulty.

The form keeps returning the message "Please enter a valid email address"

I have been following this tutorial: http://sleekd.com/tutorials/jquery-validation-in-ruby-on-rails/

Below is my code so far:

JS File

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#new_account").validate({
    rules: {
        "account[name]": {required:true},
        "account[email]": {required:true, email:true, remote:"/check_email"},
        "account[password]": {required:true},
        "account[gender]": {required:true}
    }
});
 });
```

Route

```
match 'check_email/:email' => 'accounts#checkEmail', :as => :check_email
```

Controller

```
 def checkEmail
account = Account.getAccountByEmail(params[:email])

respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => !account}
end
end
```

Appreciate any help.

Thank you,

Brian

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `getAccountByEmail` when you give it a known address and when you give it a new email address via the `rails console`.  For it to always return true, your variable `account` has to be `false` or `nil`.  That's where I would start.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it this exactly helps you(sorry for that), but surely worth a shot. However, do proceed first as specified in the solution by Vincent. The value of account might be the issue.

Have you checked this gem for client side validations. Its at https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations Its easy to use and you dont even need to write your own js.

There's a railscast on it too http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations